# curl: How to limit size of GET?

Tags: php, curl

I want to retrieve the first 10k bytes from a URL with curl (using PHP in my case). Is there a way to specify this? I thought CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE would do this, but it just appears to determine the size of a buffer that is reused until all of the content is retrieved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how i do it in c++

```
int offset = 0;
int size = 10*1024;

char range[256];
curl_slist_s *pHeaders = NULL;
snprintf(range, 256, "Range: bytes=%d-%d", offset, offset+size-1);

pHeaders = curl_slist_append(pHeaders, range);
curl_easy_setopt(pCurlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, pHeaders);

curl_slist_free_all(pHeaders);
pHeaders = NULL;
```

Edit: Just found out you meant in php. Ill see if i can find out how to port it.

Think this should work in php:

```
$offset = 0;
$size = 10*1024;

$a = $offset;
$b = $offset + $size-1;

curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Range: bytes=$a-$b") );
```

Comment: Unfortunately testing shows that some servers ignore Range: and return the whole object. I'm surprised there isn't a way to tell curl to actually stop receiving after some max size.

Comment: It is only supported in http 1.1 so 1.0 servers will ignore it (but they should really update to 1.1!)

Comment: Another hacky method you can do is use the curl callback (not sure if this is in php) and stop it your self after x bytes are downloaded.

Comment: As far as I can see there is CURLOPT_RANGE option.

Answer (score 2):

CURLOPT_RANGE appears to not work in PHP although it's there. At least it didn't have an impact when I tried to use it and a google search will reveal many messages of the same.

Comment: I think it's because the "Range: bytes" header isn't honored by all servers out there.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
// 1-10240 is range of downloaded bytes (10 kb = 10240 byte)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE,"1-10240");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use fread instead of curl, although I prefer curl, you can specify the size of the data you want to receive, for example:

```
$fp = @fopen($url, "r") ;

$data = "" ;
if($fp) {
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $data .= fread($fp, $size) ;
}
fclose($fp) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html='';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function($DownloadSize, $Downloaded, $UploadSize, $Uploaded){ return ($Downloaded > 10240) ? 1 : 0;});
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'write_function');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;

function write_function($handle, $data) {
    global $html;
    $html .= $data;
    if (strlen($html) > 10240) {
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return strlen($data);
}
```