# cURL size limit of get 

Tags: php, curl

I want to know if there is any way to get only a particular amount of data through cURL?

Option 1:
`curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Range: bytes=0-1000"));`
 but Its not supported by all servers

Option 2:
[Having trouble limiting download size of PHP's cURL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431703/having-trouble-limiting-download-size-of-phps-curl-function) but this function is giving me error `Failed writing body (0 != 11350)` and reading for which I found that many say its a bug.

So following the above `write_function` I tried to `curl_close($handle)` instead of `returning 0` but this throws an error `Attempt to close cURL handle from a callback`

Now the only way I can think of is parsing headers for content length `but this will eventually result in 2 requests ??` first getting headers with `CURLOPT_NOBODY` then getting full content?

Comment: Is the purpose to only fetch the first 1000 bytes from the file, or do you only need the first 1000 bytes for your processing purposes?

Comment: I am actually building a css optimizer that will crawler a website, and parse `<link>` tags for css and `<a>` for crawling other links on same domain for possibly other `unique` css files and concatenate + compress them. So as css files and raw html files generally dont go beyond 500kb I want to limit it, so black hats guys just keep on giving my server extra load but making my site parse gbs of anchor tags

Comment: You can do that with `fsockopen` and friends, but that optimization is not worth it. Remember, "premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: FYI I've seen stuff like "Failed writing body (0 != 11350)" when the disk was full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Option 2: Having trouble limiting
>   download size of PHP's cURL function
>   but this function is giving me error
>   Failed writing body (0 != 11350) and
>   reading for which I found that many
>   say its a bug.

It's not clear what you are doing there exactly. If you return 0 then cURL will signal an error, sure, but you will have read all the data you need. Just ignore the error.

Another option that you don't mention if you have tried is to use `fopen` with the `http://` wrapper. For example:

```
$h = fopen('http://example.com/file.php', 'r');
$first1000Bytes = fread($h, 1000);
fclose($h);
```

Comment: I know of fopen, but many tests have shown that curl generally tends to be 2-4 times faster then `fopen` so trying to know here if there are any other possibilities , on the side note even if it threw an error it was getting all the data ( I think this can also be because of speedy connection which resulted in buffer size equivalent to whole data, I will try excessive lengthy data for testing )

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use fopen and fgets to read a line at a time until you believe you've read enough lines, or read a character at a time using fgetc.
[fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Not sure if this is excatly what you're looking for, but should limit the amount of data gotten from the remote source.

Answer (score -5):

This seems to solve your problem:

```
mb_strlen($string, '8bit');
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question, perhaps the answer was intended for other question but was accidentally posted here.