# PHP - how to limit the result of curl

Tags: php, curl

i made a code using php and curl, which return a huge amount of data from a url. i would like to limit

the response from url using curl.

Our Code is:

```
$ch = curl_init($Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks! Any Help is Appreciated !!!

Comment: in how far would you like to limit the response?

Comment: it return number of rows. how to limit it @user871784

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431703/having-trouble-limiting-download-size-of-phps-curl-function

Comment: Rows? What kind of data is it? XML?

Answer (score 0):

Try range header:

```
$offset = 0;
$size = 10*1024;

$a = $offset;
$b = $offset + $size-1;

curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Range: bytes=$a-$b") );
```

This returns 10KB of data.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985455/curl-how-to-limit-size-of-get?rq=1)

Comment: Not all servers honour this header

Comment: FYI: Curl has an option for range. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, $a.'-'.$b);`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `file_get_contents()` you can easily do this:

```
$size = 1000;
$content = file_get_contents($url, false, null, 0, $size);
```

You can customize the request by using `stream_context_create()` and pass it as the third argument.