# Is it possible do only download a portion of a binary file

Tags: php, curl, binary

A small question concerning downloading xml files from a remote server.
I am using curl to achieve this.

The information I need in those xml files are located in the first couple of lines of code.
Now my question is :

Is it possible to download only a portion ( or a defined amount of bytes ) from these xml files , so I only have the first (let's say) 30 lines.

Those xml files are between 100 kb to 12 mb , so you understand that it would be more efficient to be able to minimize the bandwith of the curl request ( I'm talking about 1000 xml files a day at least ).

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985455/curl-how-to-limit-size-of-get

Comment: Note that a partial XML file will be invalid XML and you won't be able to parse it using an XML parser.

Comment: Will be using my own parser , so it won't be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [--range option for cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-r--range), which lets you do just that.

For HTTP, this will require the remote server to honour [HTTP/1.1 Range requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) - for example, if you specify a range -r0-10 then the following header will be transmitted

```
Range: bytes=0-10
```

If server doesn't want to honour that, it will return the entire file.

Comment: This may not work if the server you are connecting to doesn't support the CURLOPT_RANGE flag.

Comment: If this is the case , is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: @[Paolo Mulder] its probably best to check the file length after you downloaded it and if it exceeds the expected length because of the server ignoring the range option you truncate it.

Comment: @Paulo - yes, if you just want the *start* of a file, a range request isn't necessary. You could simply write a basic HTTP client to send the request and then close the connection when you'd read enough lines. See the PHP manual page on fsockopen, you should find some sample code there.