# curl get remote file and force download at same time

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a remote file and force download it to user at the same time.
I can't paste the code ,the code is too long . but the curl function works ,but the problem is it doesn't out put anything till it gets the remote file first then it force downloads it to user.

I use this to tell curl to return a callback

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, 'readCallback');
```

now in my readCallback function I do this :

```
function readCallback($curl, $stream, $maxRead){
    $read = fgets($stream, $maxRead);
    echo $read;
    return $read;
}
```

but it doesn't return anything it just waits till fetching remote file is finished.

Comment: Why do you echo *and* return?

Comment: echo is to output the downloaded parts to user,and return is for curl because it asks for a return value from callback

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exit out of a cURL fetch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491621/exit-out-of-a-curl-fetch) --- You're looking for the write callback, see here for a working example (and how you can debug that): [curl `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` PHP example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9491855/367456)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, it will use curl to get the total size of the file then download partial chunks of the file proxying it to the user so as there is no *wait* for curl to download it first, I tested this with an avi,mp4,mp3 and an exe, hope it helps:

```
<?php
$file = 'http://example.com/somefile.mp3';
download($file,2000);

/*
Set Headers
Get total size of file
Then loop through the total size incrementing a chunck size
*/
function download($file,$chunks){
    set_time_limit(0);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    $size = get_size($file);
    header('Content-Length: '.$size);

    $i = 0;
    while($i<=$size){
        //Output the chunk
        get_chunk($file,(($i==0)?$i:$i+1),((($i+$chunks)>$size)?$size:$i+$chunks));
        $i = ($i+$chunks);
    }

}

//Callback function for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, This is what prints the chunk
function chunk($ch, $str) {
    print($str);
    return strlen($str);
}

//Function to get a range of bytes from the remote file
function get_chunk($file,$start,$end){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, $start.'-'.$end);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'chunk');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

//Get total size of file
function get_size($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
    return intval($size);
}
?>
```

Comment: For a better performance consider using `readfile` and PHP stream contexts in the future. You will love it.

Comment: Were talking remote file, id love to see an example of what you mean as ive been trying to get my head around this question for an hour. :)

Comment: `readfile` works with PHP streams, e.g. you can make it fetch remote files. stream copy stream might be something worth to look in as well if it's possible to stream to PHP output directly (which I think is possible as well). However I think readfile is a bit lighter still. http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php ; http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php and finally: http://ua2.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: is there any chance to add http_auth ? i did it and now my curl not working     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'u:p');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Why does it restrict the download speed to a few kbps on the client side?

Comment: Isn't it the chunk size that is making the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Try using curl like this:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
        
$msg = new HttpMessage($result);
return $msg->getBody();
```

The return value then is the content of the requested file, which you can then output. So no need for a callback. [HTTPMessage docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httpmessage.php).

Comment: but doesn't this wait till the file finishes the download by curl then outputs it ?

Comment: Yes it does, but is that negative? The transfer should be incredibly fast as this is from one server to another and probably a lot faster that your client connection. And you can cache those files locally so the next user requesting the same file will get a faster response. Have you measured the difference of download time of the two methods?

Comment: well I want to cache them as I present it to user, as I download it to server myself I let the user download it in other side and as I download it I can cache it myself,and the users speed can't be more than servers even if it is I can limit it.

Answer (score 0):

how to get **big** (8GB) remote file and force download at same time, while not killing you server:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com/bigfile.mp4';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($url).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

readfile($url);
```

the [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function will read the stream in chunks, and print it to the output, so it will not use much memory...