# cURL - Downloading a file (wrong size)

Tags: php, file, video, curl, stream

I want to get a video file from another server, and open it on my website in flowplayer.

I did this :

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/file.flv');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        header("Content-Type: video/flv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=video.flv;" );
        header("Content-Length: ".$size);
        readfile($result);
```

But there is a problem with the size of file, it always shows wrong size of file (too small)

I have to use a cURL, because only my server IP can get a video from video server.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

[readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is used to reads a file and write it to the output, use echo instead of, otherwise, use strlen to get content length, try the code below:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/file.flv');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$size = strlen($result);
header("Content-Type: video/flv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=video.flv;" );
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found another problem, when I used your method, the script firstly try to download the file (I think to get an information how big is the file) and after that its working. When I try to run just the script without flowplayer, it takes about 20 min to load the website and after this 20 min the download window popup. Is there is any faster way to do this ?? without waiting 20 min for the server to check how big the file is ?? is it possible to calculate the size of the file in real time ? when the video will playing in flowplayer ?

Comment: I think what you need is chunked transfer, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991443/curl-get-remote-file-and-force-download-at-same-time).